# Where do I write the code to handle my exception?

Tags: java, exception, throws

Alright. So I have this class called "PayrollDemo", which uses a class called "Payroll". I have already set up a couple of exception classes that will manage certain exceptions, now I just need to figure out how to throw these exceptions.

I figure, I should do this via a series of if statements that check each field entered for the proper criteria. The problem is, since the exception handling is down in a different class than the one I'm working in, I'm not sure how I can throw it.

So here I'm making sure that the name string isn't empty, if it is it's supposed to cause an exception called "InvalidNameException" and throws it to an "InvalidNameException" class that I have in the same folder as my "PayrollDemo" class.

```
public class PayrollDemo
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Payroll pr = new Payroll ("Test Name", 234);

  System.out.println("Current Employee Information. \n");
  System.out.println("Name: " + pr.getName());
  System.out.println("ID: " + pr.getID());
  System.out.println("Hourly Pay Rate: " + pr.getHourlyPayRate());
  System.out.println("Number Hours Worked: " + pr.getNumHoursWorked());
  System.out.println("Gross Pay: $" + pr.calculateGrossPay() + "\n");

  System.out.println("Welcome to the payroll screen. \n");
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Please enter a name: ");
  String newName = keyboard.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Please enter an ID: ");
  int newID = keyboard.nextInt();
  pr.setID(newID);
  System.out.print("Please enter an hourly pay rate: ");
  double newPayRate = keyboard.nextDouble();
  pr.setHourlyPayRate(newPayRate);
  System.out.print("Please enter the number of hours worked: ");
  int newHours = keyboard.nextInt();
  pr.setNumHoursWorked(newHours);

  if (newName == "")
  {
     throw new InvalidNameException();
  }
  else
  {
     pr.setName(newName);
  }
```

Here is the InvalidNameException

```
public class InvalidNameException extends Exception
{
/**
    No-arg constructor
*/

public InvalidNameException()
 {
    super("Invalid name");
 }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I'm not clear on what exactly is your question. Could you clarify exactly what it is you're asking?

Comment: What do these classes that will handle the exceptions look like?

Comment: `string == ""` will never be true

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - I'm wondering how I can throw an exception to another class. Like for my InvalidNameException. That is another class I have in the same folder as PayrollDemo. What I want it to do is to check if the name the user enters is an empty string, and if it is it's meant to throw this exception to the exception class which will take care of it. If all is good it'll continue as normal.

Comment: @EvanKnowles - In the main post, the second set of code is the InvalidNameException class.

Comment: See my answer - just editing to clarify further

Comment: @PeterRader - It will be if the user enters nothing for the string. The value for newName is based off user input.

Comment: @WillTroll `==` denotes object identity, not equality. You can have 2 separate String objects, both zero-length, such that `string1 == string2` is false but `string1.equals(string2)` is true

Comment: Your question shows that you need to learn the principles of exception handling - you'll be better reading a tutorial than asking questions here.

Comment: @WillTroll and also a little bit of Java coding conventions.

Answer (score 1):

You are throwing the exception correctly. However you throw it from `main()`. It will therefore cause execution of `main()` to terminate immediately with an exception, which means the program will print a stack trace and exit, unless you enclose with a `try` block.

You need to write one method that has a `try` block and that calls another method (maybe on a different class) containing the code you posted. At the end of the `try` block you catch your InvalidNameException and do something (like sending the user back to the data entry again).

Edit:
The exception class `InvalidNameException` doesn't *handle* the exception. It *is* the exception. The only code you write on this class will be what you need to describe the exception condition - for example, you could give it a property which was the actual value of the name.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. Warning: the following code is untested its just the gist of what you want to do.

One thing you could do is make a class that handles the user input. This class reads the input, validates it, and throws any of your different kinds of exceptions:

```
public class UserInput{
    private Scanner keyboard;

    public UserInput(Scanner keyboard){

       this.keyboard = keyboard;
    }

    public String getName() throws InvalidNameException{
        System.out.print("Please enter a name: ");
        String newName = keyboard.nextLine();
        if(/*some bad condition*/){
            throw new InvalidNameException();
        }else{
            return newName;
        }
    }
}
```

Then your main method would do something like:

```
 UserInput inputReader = new UserInput(new Scanner(System.in));
 String name;
 try{
     name = inputReader.getName();
 }
 catch(InvalidNameException e){
     //do some thing with e
 }
```

Here, you wrap the methods that throw exceptions in try catch blocks, and catch the various different types of exceptions. Hope this helps